# laravel - how to modify original table attribute value for all tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Our company's DBA wants we set default value of `timestamp` table column to `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, but we have already written many programs that using `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to check `if` sentence.

We have used **Laravel 5** and **MySQL 5.6**

If there are any solution that we can change all original column value which belong to `timestamp` type to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` when the time is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I need it automatically change all tables, not just one table. thank you.

Comment: Change the SQL mode: SET SQL_MODE='NO_ZERO_DATE'

Comment: sorry i didn't explain  clearly. I can't change DB, I know laravel has getXXXAttribute method that we can change table value. but it only affect one table, I need change all timestamp columns of all tables.there are many   timestamp type columns in database. thank you for your reply!